# Characteristic classes, Möbius strip, and the cylinder

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I have been thinking how to distinguish the (open) Möbius strip from a(n open) cylinder.

**What does not work**

- Standard invariants from general topology, as connectedness or compactness,
- Invariants that depend on the mere homotopy type of the space, as homotopy groups and (co)homology.

**What does work**

The only invariant I can think of is *orientability*. My question is therefore:

> Is there any other invariant that can be used to show that the Möbius strip and a cylinder are not homeomorphic?

If we regard both spaces as line bundles over the circle, we can show with the Stiefel–Whitney classes that they are *non-isomorphic vector bundles*, but this seems to be a weaker statement that being non-homeomorphic. (And moreover Stiefel–Whitney can be treated as a reformulation of the orientability argument).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the fact that if you cut the open Möbius strip around center the resulting space is connected.

Any homeomorphism from the Möbius strip to a cylinder will induce an isomorphism on fundamental groups, so if a homeomorphism existed it must send the center of the Möbius strip to a curve homotopic to a circle going around the cylinder, and removing anything homotopic to such a curve from the cylinder disconnects it.

Comment: Beautiful argument!

Comment: @PawełCzyż If you've never done it I highly endorse making a Möbius strip and cutting it, or getting a non mathematician to do so! Lots of cool stuff can happen.

Comment: This needs to be stated a little carefully as one needs to *define* the "centre" of the Moebius strip. A simple closed path on the strip *can* disconnect it. For example take a path that is at 1/3 of the width from the edge. Perhaps define the "centre" as a loop that generates the homotopy group.

Comment: How would you show that such curve disconnects the cylinder? This looks hard, a variation of Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: @JamesCameron Thanks – although I have seen it, I would not come up with your beautiful solution.

Comment: @freakish You are right, this needs a variant of the Jordan separation theorem, i.e. the that a closed curve in the plane separates it. This can be proved without very much fuss using the fundamental group. The Jordan curve theorem itself can be proved with some work using the fundamental group and can be proved pretty easily using homology, so I wouldn't necessarily think of it as "hard" in this context.

Comment: @freakish Since $S^1\times(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $S^2\setminus S^0$ it suffices to compute the reduced homology of $(S^2\setminus S^0)\setminus S$ for some embedded circle $S$. Using Mayer-Vietoris on $A=S^2\setminus S$ and $B=S^2\setminus S^0$ you easily conclude the zeroth reduced homology of the space of interest is isomorphic to the zeroth reduced homology of $S^2\setminus S$; by Jordan’s theorem this is $\cong\Bbb Z$ as we desire.

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative to James's answer, you can look at the one-point compactifications. For the cylinder, you get a space homeomorphic to a sphere with two points identified, which has $\Bbb{Z}$ for its fundamental group. For the Möbius strip you get a space homeomorphic to the real projective plane, which has $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ for its fundamental group.

[Commenters have asked why the one-point compactifications are as I propose. To see this, argue that the spaces described are compact and that removing a single point gives the cylinder or the Möbius strip as appropriate. Thus:

For the cylinder, let $N$ and $S$ be the north and south poles in $S^2$ and remove $[\{N, S\}]$ from the identification space $S^2/R$ where $R$ is the equivalence relation that identifies $N$ and $S$; the result is homeomorphic to $S^2 \setminus \{N, S\}$, which is homeomorphic to the open cylinder.

For the Möbius strip. View the real projective plane $\mathrm{RP}^2$ as the unit disc $D^2 \subseteq \Bbb{C}$ with the boundary arc from $i$ to $-i$ on the left identified with the boundary arc from $-i$ to $i$ on the right.  Now remove the origin and note that the resulting space is homeomorphic to what you would get if you removed a small closed disc centred at the origin. Now cut what you have in half along the imaginary axis and glue the two boundary arcs together. What you now have is homeomorphic to the square $[0, 1] \times (0, 1)$ with the left and right edges identified north-south to south-north, i.e., an open Möbius strip.]

Comment: Great solution! I wish there were a possibility to choose more than one "Accepted answer"...

Comment: No worries! If there are several possible answers, someone has to get there first.

Comment: How did you compute those one-point compactifications?

Comment: @FShrike: geometrical intuition that is easily justified by seeing what happens when you remove the relevant point from the proposed one-point compactifications.

Comment: In retrospect the cylinder one is obvious. The Mobius one is causing me some pain, as the real projective plane cannae really be visualised. I attach a $2$-disk to the boundary circle, winding twice, and I delete the central point of this disk. I obtain a quotient of $S^1\times[0,1)$ where $(z,0)\sim(z^2,0)$. I don't see how this forms a Mobius strip. I know the Mobius boundary circle winds twice around its central circle, so perhaps there is a link there. Any homeomorphism would have to take the base $S^1\times\{0\}$ to the boundary circle, but what to do with the open $S^1\times(0,1)$?

Comment: @FShrike Take your half open band $S^1 \times [0,1)$ and wrap it around half of the width of the Mobius band, gluing the closed edge to the center circle. This will be 2:1 on the closed edge and 1:1 elsewhere, so descends to that quotient.

Comment: The closed Mobius strip is already compact so its one point compactification is the same as its disjoint union with a point, similarly for the closed cylinder. This answer (and also the question) does seem to be about the open strip and the open cylinder, but note that if two manifolds with boundary are homeomorphic then so are their interiors by the local homology argument you mention.

Comment: The quotient of $S^1 \times [0,1)$ you get doesn't actually have boundary (as a manifold): locally at each point $(z, 0) \sim (-z, 0)$, two half disks are being glued to a disk.

Comment: Oh dear. The mistake is mine then. I did not read 'open' in the original question. I'll retract my post

Comment: @Fshrike: I've added some detail about why the one-point compactifications are as I claimed. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Mobius strip is homotopy equivalent to the cylinder, as both spaces deformation retract onto a circle.

We prove the two are not homeomorphic using *local* homology; you are right ordinary homology cannot distinguish the two as it is homotopy invariant. The local homology of a point on the Mobius strip is $\cong\Bbb Z$ for all points in the "interior" and is trivial (zero) exactly when the point lies on the boundary circle. No surprises there; this holds for all manifolds with boundary. Computing the local homology of the cylinder $S^1\times I$ we find it "is" $\Bbb Z$ on $S^1\times(0,1)$ and is trivial on the boundary $S^1\times\partial I$; again, no surprises.

However the key observation is that the homological boundary (points with trivial local homology) is path connected (a circle, even) for the Mobius strip whereas it is disconnected for the cylinder; homological boundaries are homeomorphism invariant, so are done. Or use any one of several methods to prove $S^1\times\{0,1\}$ and $S^1$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: I see, this is a nice argument and I think it works well for closed Möbius strip and closed cylinder. However, I am not sure if it works in the case with an open Möbius strip and an open cylinder – if I understand the proof correctly, in this case the homological boundary would be empty for both spaces, wouldn't it?

Comment: @PawełCzyż Yeah, I've only just now realised you asked for the Mobius strip and cylinder *without* boundary. So my answer is moot and I'll probably delete it

Comment: No, no, I think it is great: I haven't heard about homological boundaries before, so I have learned something new thanks to it.